# Alexa - Some intents not reaching the skill

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

My Alexa skill keeps getting rejected for the reason: 
'Please note "help" fails not reaching the endpoint of the skill.'

I'm using the Skill builder to build the skill, which by default implements the help intent.

My python code that I'm running on lambda has a handler for the help intent (full code can be seen at https://github.com/kkoppenhaver/last-episode/blob/master/skill.py )

```
## Handle the help intent
if intent_name == "AMAZON.HelpIntent" or intent_name == "TroubleshootIntent":
    return build_response("Last Episode", "Welcome to Last Episode. Ask me about a T.V. series. For example, when was the last episode of How I Met Your Mother?", False)
```

And when I test using their testing interface, the help intent returns this string of text as intended.

Nevertheless, it continues to get rejected. Is there something simple I'm missing? I've filed a support request with Amazon as well, but would really like to get this approved as it's a relatively simple skill.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

EDIT: Full schema

```
{
  "intents": [
{
  "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
  "samples": []
},
{
  "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
  "samples": []
},
{
  "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
  "samples": []
},
{
  "name": "GetLastEpisodeIntent",
  "samples": [
    "last episode summary for {series_name}",
    "what was the last episode of {series_name}",
    "the last episode of {series_name}",
    "about {series_name}",
    "when was the last episode of {series_name}"
  ],
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "series_name",
      "type": "AMAZON.TVSeries",
      "samples": [
        "{series_name}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
  ],
  "prompts": [
{
  "id": "Elicit.Intent-GetLastEpisodeIntent.IntentSlot-series_name",
  "promptVersion": "1.0",
  "definitionVersion": "1.0",
  "variations": [
    {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "value": "What series are you looking for?"
    }
  ]
}
  ],
  "dialog": {
"version": "1.0",
"intents": [
  {
    "name": "GetLastEpisodeIntent",
    "confirmationRequired": false,
    "prompts": {},
    "slots": [
      {
        "name": "series_name",
        "type": "AMAZON.TVSeries",
        "elicitationRequired": true,
        "confirmationRequired": false,
        "prompts": {
          "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-GetLastEpisodeIntent.IntentSlot-series_name"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add AMAZON.HelpIntent in intent schema?

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan Since I'm using the skill builder, I believe this should already be taken care of, since it's one of the built-in intents.

Comment: Well can you please share your intent schema? I have a gut feeling that "AMAZON.HelpIntent" is missing in intent schema. Also did you try by adding a log to check what is the value your are getting for "intent_name" when you say help?

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan Added to the answer. Like I said, it looks like the skill builder added it automatically.

Comment: @KeananKoppenhaver It's been half a year since you posted this question. I hope you were able to find the answer you wanted. Could you share here for people like me who are stuck with the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: @adarshdec23 Still debugging it actually. I bought an Echo dot to test on the actual device and it seems to work. The support team says my code looks like it's working so I'm still sort of stuck!

Comment: @KeananKoppenhaver For me it turns our the problem was with my code. I did not completely understand the difference between a response and a re-prompt. So my code would output a re-prompt text when help was asked for instead of a "response".
I hope this helps someone!